# No slider images being displayed inspite of getting data correctly from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, carousel

I have a template of my application in which there is carousal used for slider images.

I want to display images to the slider through json but the images are not getting displayed.

If i try to display images without slider it works.

But then i want those images inside the carousal.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="../www/img/splash/splash-icon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="../www/img/splash/splash-screen.png"            media="screen and (max-device-width: 320px)" />  
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="../www/img/splash/splash-screen@2x.png"         media="(max-device-width: 480px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" /> 
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="640x1096" href="../www/img/splash/splash-screen@3x.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="1024x748" href="../www/img/splash/splash-screen-ipad-landscape" media="screen and (min-device-width : 481px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape)" />
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="768x1004" href="../www/img/splash/splash-screen-ipad-portrait.png" media="screen and (min-device-width : 481px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait)" />
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="1536x2008" href="../www/img/splash/splash-screen-ipad-portrait-retina.png"   media="(device-width: 768px)  and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="1496x2048" href="../www/img/splash/splash-screen-ipad-landscape-retina.png"   media="(device-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape)    and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"/>

<title>Hello There!</title>

<link href="../www/css/style.css"           rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="../www/css/colors/default.css"   rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="pagestyle">
<link href="../www/css/framework.css"       rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="../www/css/owl.carousel.css"     rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="../www/css/owl.theme.css"       rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="../www/css/swipebox.css"         rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="../www/css/colorbox.css"         rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="../www/js/index.js"></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../www/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../www/js/jqueryui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../www/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../www/js/jquery.swipebox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../www/js/colorbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../www/js/snap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../www/js/contact.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../www/js/custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../www/js/framework.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../www/js/framework.launcher.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="preloader">
    <div id="status">
        <p class="center-text">
            Loading the content...
            <em>Loading depends on your connection speed!</em>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="all-elements">
    <div id="sidebar" class="page-sidebar">
        <div class="page-sidebar-scroll">
            <div class="sidebar-content-background">
                <div class="sidebar-section">
                    <a href="#" class="sidebar-close"></a>
                    <em>Navigation</em>
                </div>
                <div class="sidebar-decoration"></div>         
                <a href="#" class="sidebar-logo"></a>              
                <div class="sidebar-decoration"></div>                   

                <div class="sidebar-navigation">     


                    <div class="nav-item">
                        <a href="index.html" class="active-nav">Homepage</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="nav-item">
                        <a href="../www/about.html" class="nav-regular">About Us</a>

                    </div>

                     <div class="nav-item">
                        <a href="../www/gallery.html" class="nav-regular">Gallery</a>

                    </div> 
                     <div class="nav-item">
                        <a href="../www/menu.html" class="nav-regular">Menu</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="nav-item">
                        <a href="../www/contact.html" class="nav-regular">Contact</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-regular close-sidebar">Close</a>
                    </div>                    
                </div>


                <br><br><br><br><br>

                <div class="sidebar-decoration"></div>

                <p class="sidebar-copyright">Copyright 2016. All rights reserved</p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
    </div>


    <div id="content" class="page-content">   

        <div class="content-controls">
            <a href="#" class="deploy-sidebar"></a>
            <em>HOMEPAGE</em>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <div class="decoration"></div>


            <div class="container ">
                <div class="slider-controls" data-snap-ignore="true">                


                </div>
                <a href="#" class="next-slider"></a>
                <a href="#" class="prev-slider"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="decoration"></div>
            <div class="container no-bottom fine">

            </div>

            <div class="decoration"></div>



            <div class="container">
                <div class="footer-socials">
                    <a href="#" class="facebook-footer"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="goup-footer"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="twitter-footer"></a>
                </div>
                <p class="copyright uppercase center-text no-bottom">Copyright 2016<br> All rights reserved</p>        
            </div> 
        </div> 

        </div>           
    </div>  
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var url = 'http://localhost/1/libs/homepage.php?home=home';
            $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(index, data) {
                $('.fine').append(data);

            });
         });
        });

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function onDeviceReady() {
            checkConnection();
        }

        function checkConnection() {
            var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

            var states = {};
            states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = '1';
            states[Connection.ETHERNET] = '1';
            states[Connection.WIFI]     = '1';
            states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = '1';
            states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = '1';
            states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = '1';
            states[Connection.CELL]     = '1';
            states[Connection.NONE]     = '0';

            if (states[networkState] == '1'){
                // Do nothing..
            } else {
                window.plugins.toast.show('No Network Connection','long','bottom');
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('.fine').append('<center><br /><br /><h4 style="color:#006699">You Seem to be offline!</h4> <a href="#" onclick="return reFresh()" class="btn btn-warning btn-block">Check your connection & Click here to Try Again</a></center><br /><br /><br /><br />');
                });
            }
        }

        function reFresh() {
            location.reload();
        }
        </script>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var url = 'http://localhost/1/libs/sliderpage.php';
            $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(index, data) {
                $('.slider-controls').append('<div><img src="http://localhost/1/gangster/screenshots/slider/'+data.img+'"></div>');

            });
         });
        });

    </script>


<script type="text/javascript">
function swapStyleSheet(sheet){
    document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', sheet);
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

[Following is the screenshot where in the empty place, i want my images to be displayed as carousal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDfHD.png) Please help me to solve this and check whether the syntax is correct or not.

Comment: Can you post the complete code, pls ?

Comment: yes.. just a moment please. sorry for the trouble.